# Wait until a animation is completed in html

Tags: jquery, html, velocity.js

I know how to wait until a **jquery** animation is completed but what if i want to wait for animation to be completed which is not performed using **jquery**. For instance i am performing a animation using **velocity.js** and want to perform a **jquery** operation once the animation is completed..!The typically methods used for **jquery** does not seem to work.Please help!

Comment: Your question is vague but you can create a custom animation function.
For example make a while loop that changes a value every time and animates a property of the element you are animating. After the loop is completed you can perform another task

Answer (score 0):

I've not used velocity.js professionally before but I believe you can just chain the jQuery to the animation sequence. [Documentation is here](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#chaining).

I have forked their Codepen and added a jQuery function to the end of the animation sequence so you can see it working.

```
$("div")
    .velocity({ width: 200 }, 1500)
    $('.test').fadeIn('fast');
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwodqY)

As with all frameworks, I suggest that you familiarise yourself with the documentation before jumping in ;)

Comment: the code you have presented in Codepen does not work.The last fadeIn() method of jquery in not working!

Comment: Works fine for me. Safari, Chrome, Firefox. I suggest read the documentation for browser compatibility and also check your console for any errors.